# Converting a 3 way circuit from controlling outlets to controlling a fan

Tags: electrical, switch, fans, light

I have two switches in the livingroom that control the outlets in the room. We never use them and in fact since we swapped out all the outlets due to age, we didn't split them so they're hot all the time regardless.

I'm in the process of converting some switches into smart switches and already ran a 2 pole wire in my office to control the light and fan separately. I'd like to do that in the livingroom as well, only difference is there will be two switches for the light instead of just one.

What I've done so far is ran a second 2 pole wire from the ceiling fan down to one of the switches. So I have a black and white wire from the light (what I want to toggle). Currently the 3 way switch has three wires, one red connected to the traveler that goes to the other switch. One black that goes to the other switch as well, and another red in the common that's going to the outlets.

The other switch has one red wire and a black wire (black is in the traveler) going to the same source. There's a black wire in the common going somewhere else. Unfortunately I'm unable to determine where exactly everything is going on the second switch.

[image: Switch 1]

[image: Switch 2]

Any good advice is great. If more information is needed, please ask and I'll do my best to find out.

Thank you in advanced for any help.

Comment: Your switches need ground wires connected.

Comment: You'll also probably hear it from others, about using the backstab terminals on the switches.

Comment: Which switch did you run the new cable to?

Comment: Thanks, this is the work of the contractors. Grounds are all connected together and bundled in the back.

The first picture, (switch 1) is the three way I want to run to the light (the white cable coming out of the wall). The switch next to it is a simple switch to the fan. The second picture, (switch 2) is the other three way switch on the circuit I would also like to control the light.

If it can be done in this manner, then great, otherwise the ultimatum is to take one of the 3-way switches out and simply cover it up. I'm going to be replacing these with smart switches/dimmer.

Comment: NEC 404.9(B) requires that switches themselves are grounded. It allows this to happen via mounting with metal screws in a metal box, but in a non-metallic box the ground must be connected to the switch via integral ground connector (green screw on your switch). Some non-metallic boxes do have a ground strap connected to the screw terminals, but yours doesn't appear to be of that type. If a contractor did this install, it's a red flag they don't know what they're doing as it's a pretty clear code violation, and you should now be highly skeptical of anything else they touched.

Comment: The entire house is like this, and has been for 30 years. As I've been going through and replacing and upgrading things, I've been attaching the grounds to everything just because that makes sense and it doesn't hurt.
---
Regardless, still looking for an answer to my original question.

Comment: Make sure you're not deleting a switch which is mandatory for lighting.  Every room must have a light switch that works, with a huge exception cut in for switched outlets.  I'm not a fan of that.  Neither are EMTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I got it. A little research and wire tracing, I figured I had this setup:

[image: Setup]

So I followed that diagram, wired the traveler to a hot wire so the outlets would always stay on, and everything worked. Even grounded the switches. Decent little setup now so if anyone in the future wanted to revert back, they could easily do so behind the switches.

Lessons learned: The internet doesn't answer your questions, just points out what else is wrong.

Hope that diagram helps anyone else dealing with stuff like this.